# An interactive vector addition simulator offsets vectors - why?

Tags: vectors

I am looking at a vector addition simulator on both PHET and physicsclassroom.com.  And I noticed something odd about the graphical vector addition. I have attached the image to show it, but the short version is that I would have expected the pink resultant to originate at the tail end of the blue vector and connect with the red one. My question is why is it offset? Assuming you are just adding two vectors of length 3, at 90 degrees to each other, you'd get the third one being $3\sqrt{2}$ long and pointing at 45 degrees from the end of the first.

Anyhow I am sure it's some obvious mathematical convention, but I wanted to check hat I wasn't missing something really important.
[image]
[image]

Comment: A parallel translation of a vector is deemed equal to the original.  It is the same vector.

Comment: So it's just a case of the simulator putting it elsewhere on the field so we can see it more easily?

Comment: That would be a reasonable guess.